# Email escalation - should I include the party being escalated in CC?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, email

There is a task that needs to be done by a team within 10 days. I have repeatedly emailed them(we are not supposed to call them, per company policy), used their ticketing system to submit ticket, but no response/acknowlegement was given. I am thinking of escalating the issue as 30 days has passed now. My question is should I include them in CC  in the escalation mail that I am about to send?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why shouldn't you? Them knowing the problem is being escalated would be in everyones interest.

When they don't know (or don't believe) that the problem got escalated, they will keep doing what they are doing right now. They won't change their behavior until the party you escalate to found the time to act on the escalation and inform them about your complaint. Depending on the diligence of the involved manager(s), this can mean an additional delay of a few hours to a few days. And then they will likely be surprised by the complaint and will ask for additional time to find out what your request was about and why they didn't do it yet.

But when they know the problem is being escalated, they gain some additional time to act on the escalation. They can use the time between you sending the escalation email and them being contacted by their boss because of it to either fulfill your request or to formulate a response why they don't do it.

They might even contact their manager before the manager contacts them (usually a smart move from their perspective), saving the manager some time and further speeding up the process.

In any case, you will get your response faster, no matter if it's positive or negative.

Answer (score 9):

You always should.

Reasons:

- Escalation is not about assigning a blame.
- Escalation only means that you are notifying the higher-ups regarding the delay. The delay might be due to legitimate issues which were not noticed by those in charge.
- By not including the other party in the CC list, you are breaking the communication further. In future, if they need to be notified about the same, you'll have to go into the trouble of attaching the escalation mails which is inconvenient.

I would ask you to also include the other party's immediate superior in the CC list to bring to their attention the delay.